# Which function in django creates a HttpRequest instance and hands to a view?

Tags: django

Am try to understand the guts of django, and i cant get any good tutorial on this.

I know django views receive a HttpRequest instance as one of the arguments when they are called,  what i would like to know is what function in django internals receive the request from the browser, creates the HttpRequest instance and hands it over to the right view?

Hope am clear!

Gath.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> HttpRequest()
<HttpRequest
GET:{},
POST:{},
COOKIES:{},
META:{}>
```

If you need this for testing and emulating requests, that's fine, but if you try to use this to call views from one another, it's inefficient.

Comment: What should you do if you do want to call views from one another? If not that?

Answer (score 6):

`django.core.handlers.base.BaseHandler` is responsible for sending the request through the middleware and then on to the view. The concrete handlers in `django.core.handlers` are what actually generate the request object in the first place.

Comment: Interesting. Let me dig in and see, btw where can i get some sort of detailed workflow of django internals, showing all the gory functions calls ...

Comment: Damfino. I just mucked around given my basic knowledge of how it all sort of fits together.