# ways to process a post request in django view and re-send it to another view

Tags: django

I have a view that receives a post request from HTML form, and i like to do some process and then send another post request to another view with some of the original data, and some more data that i add to it,

i read that HTTP does not allow to pass the same post request you received.

i read the official documentation and don't find a way of doing so, and i read about the library requests, and when i tried using it and then send the request i made by `httpresponseredirect`, it keeps sending it as post by writing tons of things in the address bar, and it kind of looks like it tries to use get instead of post.

i found here these questions:

[Which function in django creates a HttpRequest instance and hands to a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162430/which-function-in-django-creates-a-httprequest-instance-and-hands-to-a-view)

[Simulating a POST request in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370090/simulating-a-post-request-in-django)

but i don't understand from it how can i create a request in an efficient way, from my django app, and send it to another view of even another app.

```
post_data = {'name': 'something'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/polls/thanks/', name =  "somthing")
content = response.content
return HttpResponseRedirect(content)
```

Comment: Where is the code you said you tried?

Comment: @selcuk added it now

Answer (score 1):

Views are nothing more than functions in python so there isn't anything stopping you from just passing the parameters into a separate view. Whether or not thats always a good thing is a different thing

```
def view_a(request):
    # Logic here
    return view_b(request)
```

Based on your comment:

What you're trying to do seems like a long winded way of something that can be achieved with the `.get` method

```
last_name = request.POST.get('last_name', generate_name())
```

What this would do is use the last name if its provided, otherwise it will generate one.

If you're using a form, you can do the same kind of thing, just in the clean method

```
def clean_last_name(self):
    last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
    if last_name:
        return last_name
    else:
        return generate_name()
```

Comment: @captainshai - What does that mean? What is "it"? What "changes"?

Comment: i am trying to learn how to get a request from html form, make some processing and send some of it, with changes, in another request to another view. let's say that you fill your name in an html form, i want to check in one view if the form isvalid == true, and if so, i want to generate you a random last name, and send the request that you sent to me, and add to it the last name and send it to another view that does something else

Comment: @captainshai - Please see my edit... I can't see what you'd actually gain by having a load of partial functions

Comment: @captainshai: so you want to involve the client's browser in some processing you want to do that's entirely on the server side. That's not the way to do it.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich i want to do it all on the server, but the problem is, that sometimes i need to send information from one part of my app to another part, and get method is not good for me, because i don't know how many variables i will send, i need it to be flexible in the number of vars.

Comment: @captainshai: put your actual code in normal Python functions, not in views. Keep your views _tiny_. Then you can call functions with various argument lists and can keep HTTP and the browser out of the picture. The part of your code that knows it has a Web interface should be as small as possible.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich thanks for the advice, i will remember that, but if i still need to send some data from my one django app to another django app, and i dont like to pass via the database and i try to avoid cookies and sessions, how can i generate a post or get request and send it to another django app\url ?                  thanks!